# How to display data from SQLite database in different textviews as childs in Expandable ListView

Tags: android

I am able to retrieve data from SQLite database(to be precise 3 columns) and display them in Expandable Listview as Child(s). But I want to display them as:

Due date: 10/23/2016

late sub: YES

Penalty: 10%

Above, Left side text, I am displaying from Textview text(Child xml) and right side text after the colon, I am retrieving from database.

How do I handle this in getChildView method in my Adapter?

Here is my Adapter class code:

```
public class AssignmentDisplayAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<CourseDisplay>> expandableListDetail;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public AssignmentDisplayAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                HashMap<String, List<CourseDisplay>> expandableListDetail) {

    this.mContext = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_expandable_child, null);
    }
    TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.assign_duedate_display);
    expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_expandable_parent, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.parent_text);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}
}//end class
```

Here is my parent xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parent_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my child xml code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assign_duedatetext_display"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Due Date: "
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/assign_duedate_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/assign_duedatetext_display"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assign_latesubtext_display"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Late Submission: "
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/assign_latesub_display"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/assign_latesubtext_display"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assign_penaltytext_display"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Penalty: "
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/assign_penalty_display"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/assign_penaltytext_display"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe something needs to be done in getChildView method but not sure how to handle this. Please guide me through this.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to think about each row like a layout made of two sub-layouts vertically disposed. The top layout is the "header", the bottom layout will contain your TextViews. The bottom layout is not displayed, but it will be shown when the user clicks on the top layout. You can do this by setting a onClickListener on the top row and changing visibility of the bottom view inside it. To change the visibility you can use View.setVisibility(int visibility) Method

Comment: I will try that and see. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I have posted my answer. I have found a way to update the text dynamically in the code. Anyway I will give it a try with your suggestion. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this dynamically as I know the data format in the database is going to be the same for each parent.

Here is updated getChildView() Method:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_expandable_child, null);
    }
    TextView expandedListTextView1 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.assign_duedate_display);

    TextView expandedListTextView2 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.assign_duedatetext_display);


    if (expandedListPosition == 0){
        expandedListTextView2.setText("Due date: ");
    }else if(expandedListPosition == 1){
        expandedListTextView2.setText("late submission: ");
    }else {
        expandedListTextView2.setText("Penalty: ");
    }
    expandedListTextView1.setText(expandedListText);

    return convertView;
}
```